# IE7 Only Stylesheet in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-7, browser-detection

I need an IE7 only stylesheet in my ASP.net MVC project.

What is the better approach to doing this:

```
<!--[if IE 7]><link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/IE7.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
```

OR

```
@if(Request.Browser.Browser == "IE" && Request.Browser.MajorVersion >= 7 && Request.Browser.MajorVersion < 8) {
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/IE7.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}
```

Is there a preferred way to do this in MVC or are they pretty much equal?

Comment: What is wrong with it? What better approach you need? Listed ones is most popular.

Comment: Nothing wrong with either, but I would like to know which is the more preferred MVC way (if any)

Comment: Absolutely go with the first method, the IE conditional comments. Much more reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two options do totally different things. The first, `[if IE 7]` lets the *browser* decide what to render. The second makes the server decide.

The first will work with caching layers which presume that all browsers should see the same markup. The second will not.

Also, consider [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) rather than rolling your own IE 7 support.

Comment: Does Modernizr have any way to fix the IE7 z-index bug? I am using a Telerik Grid control and the filter is getting hidden behind other div tags in IE7. I tried setting z-index but it doesn't work in IE7.